# Dialog inside map function doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data (objects) that I have saved in my state (workitems). I map them out to a table and it works as it should. However, when I try to implement a Dialog with a button to it where the user can see more info about that particular object,the dialog will open but show wrong info from another object. That is, the table cells info (title, description etc) is not the same as the title and description in the dialog for some reason.

This works:

```
                 {this.state.workitems.map((workitem) => {
                        return (

                            <tr className={this.showOrHide(workitem)}>


                                <td>


                                    <Text variant={"large"}>

                                        {workitem.company ? workitem.company + " - " : ""}

                                        <a href={workitem.url} target="_blank">{workitem.title}</a>
                                        <div className="description pt-2">
                                            <p>{workitem.status ? workitem.status : null}</p>


                                            </Dialog>
                                            <strong>Description: </strong>
                                            {workitem.description
                                                ? this.trimWord(workitem.description.replace("...", ""), 299, "...")
                                                : ""}{" "}
                                            ...

                                     </div>

                                    </Text>
                                </td>
```

However, when I try to add the dialog it doesnt as explained above:

```
{this.state.workitems.map((workitem) => {
                        return (

                            <tr className={this.showOrHide(workitem)}>


                                <td>


                                    <Text variant={"large"}>

                                        {workitem.company ? workitem.company + " - " : ""}

                                        <a href={workitem.url} target="_blank">{workitem.title}</a>
                                        <div className="description pt-2">
                                            <p>{workitem.status ? workitem.status : null}</p>
                                            <DefaultButton secondaryText="Open" onClick={this._showDialog} text="Open Dialog" key={workitem.description} />
                                            <Dialog
                                                hidden={this.state.hideDialog}
                                                title={workitem.title}
                                                subText={workitem.description}


                                            >

                                                <DialogFooter> <DefaultButton text="Close" onClick={() => (this.setState({ hideDialog: true }))} /></DialogFooter>

                                            </Dialog>
                                            <strong>Description: </strong>
                                            {workitem.description
                                                ? this.trimWord(workitem.description.replace("...", ""), 299, "...")
                                                : ""}{" "}
                                            ...

                                     </div>

                                    </Text>
                                </td>
```

How come the mapped out properties are not the same inside of the dialog as the outside ones?

Comment: Dialog code is needed to see what happens there, passing params look correct

Comment: I use office ui fabric and for some reason it doesn't seem to work.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/dialog

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is probably that you are mapping over your `workitems` array and rendering a separate dialog for each item.  However, you are controlling the display of **all** the dialogs with only a single `hideDialog` flag in your state.  This will cause every dialog to show when you only want one to be shown.

I think the answer here is to move your `<Dialog/>` component outside of the map statement, and instead store the selected item in your state when it is selected and pass it down to the dialog as a prop.

Tough to give a complete example without seeing the entire component (is this a class or functional component?).  If you post the complete code I can try giving you a basic idea of how it might look.